# Sending a Card via Skype REST API

Tags: rest, api, skype

I have been trying to send a Skype Card using the REST API and have had no success.

I can send and receive messages no problem but I can't seem to send a card. I have tried various JSON payloads, here's my last attempt...

```
{
    "type": "message/card.carousel",
    "summary": "Several hotel offers in Paris",
    "text": "Here you have hotels you're looking for",
    "attachments": [{
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
        "content": {
            "title": "I'm a hero card",
            "subtitle": "Pig Latin Wikipedia Page",
            "images": [{
                "url": "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQo8Tn7RWwELr74w4irLgnhEKHGdDnMYFA-IBXbsaupp6DE697wdKmNbPE"
            }],
            "buttons": [{
                "type": "openUrl",
                "title": "WikiPedia Page",
                "value": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

The image is just a random one I pulled out of google search.
I'm using a proprietary server that allows for sending of HTTP requests, it's not ASP, JSP, Python or Pearl :)

Has anyone managed to get this going, documentation is thin on the ground!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was working all along! I tried it on my mobile phone and it was appearing so I looked to see if there was a Skype update for PC and after installing it it worked fine.